# Where can I buy a Chumash with Rashi in English?

Tags: rashi, translation, pentateuch-chumash, english

Does anyone know where I could get a complete Chumash with Rashi's commentary in English?

Comment: A favourite oldie is the [Silberman Chumash](http://www.amazon.com/Chumash-Commentary-Bereishith-Shemoth-Bemidbar/dp/0873060199)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get it all [online here](http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/63255/jewish/The-Bible-with-Rashi.htm)

or buy [this ArtScroll set](http://www.artscroll.com/Books/9781578191147.html).

You can also go old school and get [the JPS set](http://www.abebooks.co.uk/book-search/title/the-pentateuch-and-rashi's-commentary-a-linear-translation-into-english-deuteronomy/author/isaiah-rabbi-abraham-ben-and-rabbi-benjamin-sharfman/) (that's the link for Devarim).

Answer (score 3):

Any Jewish book store near where you live or online. [Judaica World](http://www.judaica-world.com/sapirstein-edition-rashi-5-volume-slipcase-set-student-size.html), [Judaica Press](http://www.judaicapress.com/products/metsudah-hebrew-english-chumash-rashi-5-vol-set-student-size), Koren, ArtScroll, World of Judaica, Eichlers, and even [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0873060199) will have this. You can even go online and find it for free at ... http://www.chabad.org/library/bible_cdo/aid/63255/jewish/The-Bible-with-Rashi.htm

Answer (score 1):

See the set I grew up with on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000GW3J50) and [WorldCat](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/3430175). It is linear: each line of Hebrew has its translation near it. As far as I recall (though it's been a few years), it has a clear font (with *Rashi* in block, not "*Rashi*", script) and nice spacing between the lines, but a more opaque English.